# Write a program that will do the work of the GUI via command line

Tags: c#, user-interface, cmd, cygwin

I have a GUI and I need to perform the function of the GUI via a command line. Is there a way to write a c# program to do so. The GUI is as follows:

[image]

I have a Cygwin command line program that should compile my C# program. My task is to have the script to do something of this sort *--device abc --sim 123 --profile 2 connect* as per the GUI image that I have attached.

Comment: Not trying to be snarky, but do you want us to do your task? Or do you have some specific impediments?

Comment: @Vikhram I am having impediment in understanding the scripting task like is it possible to override the GUI with a script using C# or any other command line. I do not know if it is feasible so just wanted an opinion.

Comment: If you have control over the code of the GUI program, you can make it work from command-line and from GUI. If the GUI program's code is out of your hand, and assuming it does not offer any command-line options, you cannot trivially make an external script/program accept command-line arguments.

Comment: @Vikhram You mean to say that if I have the code of the application like the back end part and the visual display design then I can think about doing command line right?

Comment: Correct. Don't forget that once you obtain the command line args you will have to wire the obtained args to the appropriate method calls or "button click"s

Comment: Have you read the documentation of your application and/or tried to get help with `application.exe /?`

Comment: @Stephan Yes tried doing so but it is more of a user manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tell us nothing about the software that generates the GUI, your question can only be answered in very generic terms. And this answer is: No.

No, there is no generic way to write a script that feeds input into another program's GUI.

There are programs that record and replay mouse movements and keyboard input. You could use them to redo repetitive GUI input. But probably you are asking for a parametric script that allows for variations of the GUI operations. Then again: there is no generic solution.